# How to iterate every nth row and loop again?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to sample data.

For example

1. If 552 rows, start sampling from 2nd row
2. For the sample frequency calculated, for example 8.
   Every 8th row from 2nd row to be marked "Yes".
   If it does cover the entire data, loop to select 8th row again, leaving out the rows already selected.

```vb
Sub Sampling()

    Dim rngDataRange As Range
    Dim rngCombRange As Range
    Dim intRowNum, i As Integer
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Yardi Report")
    intRowNum = 1
    Set rngCombRange = Range(intRowNum & ":" & intRowNum + 5)
    For i = 1 To 552
        If intRowNum + 5 > 552 Then
            intRowNum = 5 - (552 - intRowNum) + 1
        Else
            intRowNum = intRowNum + 5
        End If
            
        Set rngDataRange = Range(intRowNum & ":" & intRowNum + 5)
        Set rngCombRange = Union(rngCombRange, rngDataRange)
        rngCombRange.Select
        Range(DSheet.Cells(rngCombRange.Row, "Q")).Interior.Color = 49407
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Check For loops. Something like `For 2 to 552 Step 8` should work. *have no idea how to do it* then read [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office)

Comment: But It should loop back again if 50 samples are not selected

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Sampling()

Dim maxRows As Long
Dim i As Long

Dim sampleSize As Long
Dim numSelected As Long

Dim DSheet As Worksheet

Set DSheet = Worksheets("Yardi Report")

StartRow = 2    ' data starts in row 2
newStartRow = StartRow

maxRows = 552   ' data ends in row 552

numSelected = 0

sampleStep = 8      ' Adjust as needed
sampleSize = 80     ' Adjust as needed

Do While numSelected < sampleSize
    
    For i = newStartRow To maxRows Step sampleStep
    
        Cells(i, 2) = "Yes"
        numSelected = numSelected + 1
        Debug.Print "Sample: " & numSelected
        
        If numSelected = sampleSize Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        
    Next
    
    newStartRow = newStartRow + 1
    Debug.Print "newStartRow: " & newStartRow
    Debug.Print "StartRow...: " & StartRow
    
    If numSelected < sampleSize Then
        Debug.Print "sampleStep + StartRow: " & sampleStep + StartRow
        
        If newStartRow = sampleStep + StartRow Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    End If
    
Loop

Debug.Print "Done " & Now

End Sub
```